# Counting roots inside the unit circle for a particularly simple polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

Let $\phi>1$, $K\in\mathbb{N}$ and $L\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I am interested in the roots of the equation:
$$\frac{1}{K}\sum_{k=1}^K{z^{k-L}}=\phi.$$
(As written, this is not a polynomial, as $1-L$ may be negative, but multiplied by $z^{\max{\{0,-(1-L)\}}}$ it is.)

I would like to know how many complex roots are inside the unit circle, and how many are outside. Based on the context and numerical tests I conjecture that $\max{\{0,-(1-L)\}}$ are inside the unit circle, and $\max{\{0,K-L\}}$ are outside of the unit circle. Is this correct? Does it have a simple proof?

I played around with the Jury stability criterion, but it seemed like too heavy machinery for such a simple question. I also tried multiplying the equation by $(1-z^{-1})$ in order to telescope the sum, but it was not obviously helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is obvious that if $L \le 1$ there are zero roots inside the unit circle and similarly if $K  \le L$ there are zero roots outside.

For $L >1$ the equation becomes $\frac{1+z+..+z^{K-1}}{K}=\phi z^{L-1}$ and since for $|z| \le 1$ one has $|\frac{1+z+..+z^{K-1}}{K}| \le 1$ while $\phi >1$ a direct application of Rouche theorem says that the given equation has precisely as many zero inside the unit circle as $\phi z^{L-1}=0$ so exactly $L-1$

Now with $w=1/z$, the equation becomes $\frac{1+w+..+w^{K-1}}{K}=\phi w^{K-L}$ so same as before the equation has precisely $K-L$ roots $w$ inside the unit circle (hence the original equation has $K-L$ roots outside the unit circle) as long as $K >L$ (and none otherwise)so we are done!